# Is there a typo in my code that makes my function not fill in my form?

Tags: javascript, forms, function

I'm making a really simple calculation form that will take your hours and payrate then calculate your gross pay. I've tried running the function separately (changing the document.getElementById with prompts) and it works fine, and the form is displaying but the function is not filling in the grosspay readonly box. I'm putting the whole code below in case it is something silly typo wise.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gross Pay</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Payroll Form</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function grossPay() {
            var hours = document.getElementByID("hr").value;
            hours = parseFloat(hours);
            var pay = document.getElementById("pr").value;
            pay = parseFloat(pay);

            document.getElementById("gp").value = pay * hours;
        };
    </script>

    <form name="form1" id="form1">
        Hours:<input id="hr" name="hr" type="text" size="20" />
        <br /><br />
        Pay Rate $<input id="pr" name="pr" type="text" size="20" />
        <br /> <br />
        Gross Pay $<input id="gp" name="gp" type="text" size="20" readonly="readonly" />
        <br /> <br />
        <input type="button" id="button1" value="Click Me" onclick="grossPay()" />
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have a typo. Change `var hours = document.getElementByID("hr").value;`
to `var hours = document.getElementById("hr").value;`

Comment: You can use the dev tools next time to check your error logs. Read more about it [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/)

Comment: You should specify that the d in getElementById is the wrong case for clarity.